# How to force a property value to be written in to .Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a string property with following attributes set. It basically store a some SQL code which will eventually become a part of a SQL query.

```
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DefaultValue(null)]
[Localizable(false)]
```

And I want the value to be serialized in to .designer.cs file. And never written in to .resx file.

This work most of the time but when the value in this property is longer than a certain length Visual Studio place in to .resx file.

And then this value which should never be changed in localisation process get changed and create errors.

How do it make the designer never put the value in to resource file?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Content`:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```

But I'm not sure what happens to the resx file. Just try it.